# how to pass state value from child component to another component in react js

Tags: reactjs

hi i'm learning react what could be the best way to pass the state value from searchFrom.js to the searchHistory.js

```
src
-Component
    -Header.js
       -SearchFrom.js
    -SearchHistory.js
```

```
In Header.js 
    import Navbar from "./Navbar";
    import SearchFrom from "./SearchFrom";
    function Header() {
      return (
        <div className="header__wrapper">
          <Navbar />
          <SearchFrom />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Header;
```

and i want value from SearchFrom.js to SearchHistory.js

Comment: you can use context api which will make it available globally the props are transferred from parent to child in this case you are doing opposite.

Comment: Hello @Dipesh, you should more details with the lines of code. So can you please update the post with more detailing code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do:

**1.Most straight way:**
This is easier to understand with a couple of examples.
Have your state at SearchHistory or another parent component:

```
const [searchState, setSearchState ]= useState("");
```

Make a handler to change the state:

```
const searchHandler = (val) => {setSearchState(val)}
```

Pass it down to any child component that you want to access parent state:

```
<SearchHistory>
   <SearchFrom searchHandler={searchHandler}/>
</SearchHistory>
```

Inside child component you can call:

```
props.searchHandler("new search state")
```

**2.Context Api**
This like having a container, and inside that container every component can access other components state's using the "context".
[read more at react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

**3.Redux**

This is the most advanced (and arguably the best way to alter your state).
You should probably move onto redux after you are comfortable with react, you may expect to learn it in at least a week. You can use first two techniques at start, and when you are ready go with redux.

A short explanation of redux: Redux is a state manager.
You are not supposed to change other components state in react.(if you do you can't keep track of what changed your components state so it is not any different than directly changing html with jquery, you lose most of the benefits of react)
With a state manager, every component **can** change the state but they do it with **actions**. When you want to change state, you dispatch an action, your action gets to a function called a **reducer**, that function determines what to do with the action.
When you are not sure what happened to your components state, you can just view actions history and see what action updated the state.

[read more redux.js](https://redux.js.org/)

Note: As in Pramod's answer, I agree that if are not going to do any fancy stuff go with props drilling.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular use-case, you can up-lift your state to an immediate common parent i.e. App component. There will be a small `prop-drilling` in this case. But if the state is shared by multiple components and if those component doesn't have a direct relation then I would suggest using `Context` or some third-party libraries such as `redux`.

If you are just uplifting the state, you can do the following

```js
//App.js
const [state, setState] = useState({});

return(
<Header setState={setState} .../>
< SearchHistory data={state} .../>
)

//Header.js
...
return(
< SearchFrom setState={props.setState}>
)
...

//SearchFrom.js
...
//some logic to setState from here via props.setState()
...

//SearchHistory.js
//Use state here via `props.data`
```

You can read more about [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and [uplifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).